# awk search on multiple fields of a multi line record file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file with records that are of the form:

```
SMS-MT-FSM-DEL-REP
country: IN
1280363645.979354_PFS_1_1887728354

SMS-MT-FSM-DEL-REP
country: IN
1280363645.729309_PFS_1_1084296392

SMS-MO-FSM
country: IR
1280105721.484103_PFM_1_1187616097

SMS-MO-FSM
country: MO
1280105721.461090_PFM_1_882824215
```

This lends itself to parsing via awk using something like:
    awk 'BEGIN { FS="\n"; RS="" } /country:.*MO/ {print $0}'

My question is how do I use awk to search the records on 2 separate fields? For example I only want to print out records that have a country of MO AND whos record first line is SMS-MO-FSM ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you have set FS="\n", and RS="", then the first field $1 would be SMS-MO-FSM. Therefore your awk code is

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; RS=""} $2~/country.*MO/ && $1~/SMS-MO-FSM/ ' file
```

Comment: Watch out with unwanted regex matches (like `country: SMO`). I would use string comparison whenever possible and anchor all regex.

Comment: thank you but I wonder if you could answer (probably a very simple) addition to the last question. I would like to print out the result on one line (for piping into sort|uniq)> I ran your code and it worked great (thanks) but when I set OFS to " " (space) the fields of the record still came out on different lines. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code: 
    awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; RS=""; OFS=" ";} $2~/country: MO$/ && $1~/SMS-MO-FSM/ {print $0}' testFile.txt

Comment: when piping to sort, you need newlines.. i don't know how to answer your question since you don't provide enough information on your data. try setting OFS="\n" and see.

Answer (score 3):

*(I post this as a separate answer instead of a comment reply for better formatting)*

Concerning your second remark about printing a record on a single line: When you don't modify your records `OFS` and `ORS` have no effect. Only when you change `$0` or one of the fields `awk` will recompute `NF` and reconstruct `$0` based on `$1 OFS $2 OFS ... $NF ORS`. You can force this reconstruction like this:

```
BEGIN {
    FS  = "\n"
    RS  = ""
    OFS = ";"     # Or another delimiter that does not appear in your data
    ORS = "\n"
}
$2 ~ /^[ \t]*country:[ \t]*MO[ \t]*$/ && $1 ~ /^[ \t]*SMS-MO-FSM[ \t]*$ {
    $1 = $1 ""    # This forces the reconstruction
    print
}
```